# Ternary operator with index++ gives "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as statement"

Tags: c#, increment, ternary-operator

I don't get this hint text and the reason why the code doesn't compile:

```
int index = 0;
bool result = false;

result ? index++ : index--;
```

This is an increment/decrement isn't it?

Why does it give a compilation error: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"?

Comment: The answer tells you how to use this properly, but it's really just a complicated way of doing an `if` statement - I'd probably go with simple code than use a ternary operator.

Comment: It's the _ternary operator_ that the compiler is complaining about, not the increment. Personally, I would use an `if`/`else` in this case: `if(result) index++; else index--;`

Comment: Assigning the expression (_"int tmp = result ? index++ : index--;"_) would remove the error, but as others have commented using an if statement or Sami's answer below would be better.

Comment: @jPhizzle: have you tried your solution - I have seen several questions on SO asking why code similar to this does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ternary operator isn’t a statement by itself. It doesn’t matter what’s inside it, it’s about what it is itself. This would be a statement:

```
index += result ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: I get it. Thanks!